# Paypal Adeptive Response Message

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

can anyone please explain me this error message?
i am using paypal adeptive payments but all is properly setup but this error is coming in light box pop up so please explain it for me?

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 520003
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

)
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

This error message is the result of incorrect credentials being passed. You would want to make sure the credentials you are passing are correct. Note, if you are copying them from the PayPal website directly, I would recommend copy and pasting them into a text editor then copy and paste from there to your code to avoid leading or trailing spaces from occurring when pasting the information.

If your credentials are correct I would recommend reviewing your code to ensure that these credentials are not being changed or modified when being passed over to PayPal.

One thing thing you can try is if your using the sandbox for the purpose of this testing, I would recommend attempting to run it in Live mode as there can be issues occasionally with certain functions running on the sandbox environment.